# How to divide without remainders on Python

Tags: python

In this code i am trying to randomly create division questions for primary school age (10 years) so I don't want any remainders when it dividies. This is the code I have, but I am unsure on how to do the divide thing.

```
     for i in range (0,2) :
         import random
         number1 = random.randint (20,30)
         number2 = random.randint (2,5)
         answer4 = (number1 / number2)
         question4 = int(input('What is %d / %d?: ' %(number1, number2)))
         if question4 == answer4:
             print ('Well done')
             score += 1
         else:
             print ('Wrong! The answer is %d' %(answer4))
     print ('You have finished the quiz! Well done!')
     print ('Your overall score is %d out of 10' %score)
```

This is part of a part of a bigger quiz with other questions, but I was unsure of this part, so any help would be welcomed.

Comment: As in, you want the numerator to be a multiple of the denominator? Why not just take a random multiple of the denominator, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply randomize the `number2` and the answer, then multiply to get `number 1`

```
number2 = random.randint(2,5)
answer4 = random.randint(20//number2, 30//number2)
number1 = number2*answer4
```

Comment: it worked and now i have a full quiz :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 16):

You can do `5//2` and get `2` instead of the `2.5` you'd get with `5/2`.

As long as you're in Python 3
, you can also use `floor(5/2)`.

Both ways of doing it give you the floor-rounded answer.

Comment: Just keep in mind that in the given example the result will not be int 2 as you might expect but float 2.0

Answer (score 6):

In python 3, the standard division operator `/` will do "real" division, while the `//` operator will do integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiplication to arrive at the number.

```
import random as r
for i in range(0,2):
    num1 = r.randrange(2,6)
    num2 = r.randrange(2,6)
    print ("What is {}/{}".format(num1*num2,num2))
    if int(input()) == num1:
       print("Correct")
    else:
       print("Wrong, the answer is {}".format(num1))
```

With this, the quotient will always be an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer