# How to separate the Full number and Decimal Number from a Divison Result in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, division

**For python**

After division, if the result has any decimal number with the full number, I just want to get the full number and ignore the decimal number.

for example:

```
130/33 = 3.939393
```

here I just want to use the number "`3`" and ignore the "`.939393`"

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183853/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-used-for-division)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to divide without remainders on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906753/how-to-divide-without-remainders-on-python)

Comment: Do you want it rounded up, down, closest full number or literally take the integer number as it is before the decimal place?

Answer (score 2):

Use integer division:

```
print(130//33)
3
```

**SEE ALSO:**

> Also referred to as integer division. The resultant value is a whole integer, though the result’s type is not necessarily int. The result is always rounded towards minus infinity: 1//2 is 0, (-1)//2 is -1, 1//(-2) is -1, and (-1)//(-2) is 0

Numeric Types — int, float, complex: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex

---

[What is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/183853/967621)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `-130//33` will result in `-4` which is most likely undesired behavior. Converting to int with `int(-130/33)` removes the precision and results in `-3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast to `int` without using any library

```
print(int(130/33))
```

Documentation about [casting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp)

Comment: If it's any consolation, I think this is the right answer as the OP asked specifically for the number before the decimal place. int(str(number).split('.')[0]) would be the long way of doing what they, in my opinion, are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use floor method of math package.

```
import math   
  
# prints floor() method
print(math.floor(130/33))
```

Output:

```
3
```